# Android reassign view id programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When trying to change the id of an imageView, the id's don't change like I want them to change, I know it isn't very clear but here is some of my code:

```
row1Image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            row1Image.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            row2Image.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            row3Image.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            row4Image.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            row5Image.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);

        row1tile = row1ids[row2tileRand];
        row1Image.findViewById(row1tile);
        //i already tried using row1image = (ImageView)findViewById(row1tile); But that didn't work
        row1Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.audi_logo);


        row2tile = row2ids[row3tileRand];
        row2Image.findViewById(row2tile);
        row2Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.audi_logo);


        row3tile = row3ids[row4tileRand];
        row3Image.findViewById(row3tile);
        row3Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.audi_logo);


        row4tile = row4ids[row5tileRand];
        row4Image.findViewById(row4tile);
        row4Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.audi_logo);

        row5tileRand = random1.nextInt(max-min+1)-min;
        row5tile = row5ids[row5tileRand];
        row5Image.findViewById(row5tile);
        row5Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.audi_logo);
    }
});
```

As you can see, I first change the color of the imageview to transparent, and then I want it to display the image in the same column as the one above. Here is image when I start the app:

[image]

and it stays so when I click it.

Comment: Check whether the `row<somenumber>tileRand` variables actually change when you click the button. Don't know what the rest of your code does but I think you set the image id correctly.

Comment: They don't need to change, only **row5tileRand**, as you can see, the rest uses the **row<somenumber>tilerand** of the image above.